# How do I setup Joomla to use Postfix on a local machine?

Tags: emails

As title states, I need to setup Joomla on my local machine for testing, and want to use Postfix to debug mails that are sent. Any links or tips are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into mail catch solutions like:

- Mailhog https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog
- MailCatcher https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher
- Mailpit https://github.com/axllent/mailpit

From that list I only have experience with MailHog. When I need to catch the outgoing mail from a local Joomla website, I just start up a docker container with MailHog.